# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar/optimizar este código?

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++, optimización, c++17

hace dos días empecé a programar en C++ y obviamente todavía me falta mucha práctica.Para esta tarea no sé como optimizar el código y siento que hago poco escribiendo mucho. El siguiente programa supone calcular el área y perímetro de un círculo, tomando en cuenta todas las restricciones posibles (validación de datos y eso) e incluso le hice un sistema de repetición. ¿Cómo lo puedo mejorar u optimizar? 
¿Cómo puedo mejor la validación de datos? 
¿Debería definir más funciones afuera para dejar la main más vacía? ¿Estoy usando librerías innecesarias=

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <iomanip> 


using namespace std;

//Se verifica que el numero sea valido
float convertir(string numero){ //Se pone como argumento el string de la entrada
    //Si la entrada contiene algun simbolo no admitido o fuera de rango, se hace lo siguiente:
    while(cin >> numero && numero.find_first_not_of("1234567890.") != string::npos){
        //Se muestra la advertencia
        cout << endl << "Numero invalido" << endl;
        if(atof(numero.c_str()) < 0){ //si el numero ingresado es negativo, también se advierte
            cout << "El radio de un circulo no puede ser negativo." << endl;
        }
        //Se solicita nuevo numero
        cout << "Por favor intente de nuevo. " << endl << endl;
        //Se borra la entrada anterior
        cin.clear();
        //Se descarta la entrada anterior
        cin.ignore(123, '\n');
        cout << "Ingrese el radio del circulo: ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    //Si se introdujo un numero valido, se devuelve convertido a float. 
    return atof(numero.c_str());
}

//Se define el area en funcion del radio
float area(double radio){
    return M_PI * (pow(radio,2));
}

//Se define el perimetro en funcion del radio
float perimetro(double radio){
    return 2 * M_PI * radio;
}

//En caso de que sea 0, se advierte.
void handleZero(double res){
    if(res == 0){
        cout << "El radio de un circulo debe ser mayor a 0." << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    //Se define la variable tipo string donde se introducirá el numero, y 
    string radio, rep;
    //Se definen las variables en donde se almacenara e radio y los calculos
    float r, p, a;
    bool repetir; //Valor de repetición, si es verdadero el programa se reinicia para hacer las operaciones de nuevo.

    do{
        //Se solicita la entrada del radio 
        cout << "Ingrese el radio del circulo: ";
        //Se verifica y convierte el radio, y a la vez se guarda en la variable numerica
        r = convertir(radio);

        //Se evaluan las funciones en con respecto al radio, y se guardan en sus respectivas variables
        p = perimetro(r);
        a = area(r);

        //Se muestran los resultados, en fixed para evitar notacion cientifica y presicion de dos decimales
        cout << "El perimetro del circulo es " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << p << endl;
        cout << "El area del circulo es " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << a << endl;
        handleZero(r);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Desea repetir la operacion? [S/N] ";

        //se pregunta si se quiere relizar la operación de nuevo
        cin >> rep;

            if(rep == "s" || rep == "S"){
            //Si se introduce una s, mayuscula o minuscula, el valor repeteición queda verdadero y se repite el ciclo
            repetir = true;
            cout << endl;
            } else {
            //si no se introduce una s, el valor repeticion queda falso y se termina el programa. 
            repetir = false;
            }

    } while(repetir == true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0):

Más que "optimizar" (no hay nada muy escandaloso en cuanto rendimiento) hay un par de cosas raras (igual me dejo algo).

1. Al método *convertir* le pasas un parámetro "radio" que no usas para nada, es una simple variable local del método. Estaría mejor cambiar el nombre del método por *leerRadio()*.
2. Lees un *string* (`cin >> numero`) y luego conviertes a float con `atof`. Más fácil es definir `numero` como float desde el principio.
3. Tienes un método *handleZero* que ejecutas en medio del bucle principal. Si tienes algún problema con que el usuario introduzca un radio cero, deberías poner esa lógica dentro de *convertir/leerRadio*, no después de hacer todo el cálculo e imprimir los resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Una pequeña sugerencia para la parte de conversión, ya que marcaste tu pregunta con C++17. 
Una de las nuevas características de C++17 es la conversión eficiente de tipos.  Se proporciona una familia de funciones, `to_chars` y `from_chars`, que te permiten convertir a/de una cadena de caracteres a/de un tipo entero o de punto/coma flotante.

Puedes revisar documentación de C++ en español en [es.cppreference.com](https://es.cppreference.com/w/P%C3%A1gina_principal):
[from_chars](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) y
[to_chars](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars), o puedes revisar esta entrada en my blog si prefieres utilizar [plantillas de función](https://javierestrada.blog/2020/04/09/una-historia-de-conversion-mejorando-from_chars-y-to_chars-en-c17/) para la conversión: